# Folium of Descartes

Tags: calculus, algebraic-geometry, plane-curves

A colleague came to me with an interesting observation:

Consider the folium of Descartes, $$x^3+y^3=3axy$$ which upon implicit differentiation of the latter yields $$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{ay-x^2}{y^2-ax}$$
Now, the interesting observation is that if one considers the set of curves parametrized by $m\in\mathbb{R}$ $$ay-x^2=m(y^2-ax),$$ then all the curves intersect at a single point within the loop of the folium (namely, $(a,a)$).

Further experimentation yielded similar results for the family of curves $$x^n+y^n=naxy.$$  It is clear how this all "works," but what is unclear is

*Why should these curves intersect?*

Furthermore,

*Is there a name to describe this behavior/phenomenon?*

To clarify further, the point of intersection corresponds to the value where *both* the numerator and denominator in the derivative vanish (this also happens at the origin).  This is what is meant by how this "works."

Thanks!

Edit:  Added a picture to hopefully aid in my explanation.  (Curves correspond to $a=2, m=1, \frac12, -\frac{1}{2}$.)

[image: Folium]

Edit2: Fixed derivative formula.

Comment: Your derivative formula is only correct if $a=2$. For the general case, you have $$3x^2 + 3y^2y' = 3a(y + xy')$$hence $(y^2-ax)y' = ay-x^2$, hence $$y' = \frac{ay-x^2}{y^2-ax}.$$

Comment: Fixed it.  Thank-you for pointing that out.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the first question? You have an implicit curve of the form $f(x,y) = -m f(y,x)$; if $a$ is a zero of $f(x,x)$ it's no surprise that the entire family intersects at the point $(a,a)$.

Comment: @user7530:  I wholly agree.  My question is more to a higher-end reason as to why these parametrizations share this point and perhaps, in the end, a nod to some geometric reason for its existence (independent of calculus).

Comment: An observation: for even $n$, there are three intersection points at the origin and at $(\pm\sqrt[n-2]{a},\pm\sqrt[n-2]{a})$, while there are only two intersection points for odd $n$ at the origin and at $(\sqrt[n-2]{a},\sqrt[n-2]{a})$.

Answer (score 3):

You are considering the pencil of conics generated by $ay-x^2$ and $y^2-ax$. Such a pencil will have 4 common points counted with multiplicity over an algebraically closed field. The common points can be found by elimination of one of the variables: for a point on $x=y^2/a$ then $0=ay-x^2=ay-y^4/a^2$. The solutions are $y=0$ and $y^3=a^3$. The solution $y=a$ gives $x=a$, the point mentioned in the problem. The value $y=0$, yields $x=0$. The other solutions are complex.

For the other curve mentioned the derivative will have a numerator $N$ of degree $m$ and denominator $D$ of degree $d$. In this case the (projective) pencil generated by the numerator $N$ and denominator $D$ is the family of curves $N+tD=0$ for varying $t$ together with the additional curve $D=0$. By Bezout's theorem there will be $md$ common points of the pencil